# How to add Octa SSO as an IDP to Azure AD B2C Tenant SSO using custom policies?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We have a Azure AD B2C SSO implementation that we configured using custom policies. We want to add Octa as an identity provider using custom policies. I couldn't find any documentation or article how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If Okta supports OpenID Connect, you can use this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile. There are other articles for other protocols.

Comment: You can also do this with SAML so B2C becomes an SP - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs2016-custom?tabs=applications